# Conversion of portable fluorescent to UV-C lamp

Tags: dc-dc-converter, light, uv

I am modifying an off-the-shelf portable fluorescent light to a UV-C light for use in field illumination. I found a 13W UV-C 4-pin bulb that is the same physically as the OEM fluorescent, so thought I would try to convert the entire unit. I went ahead and CAD modeled the key physical elements, then created an alternate part to replace the clear acrylic lens to one that is opaque ABS and holds a custom ZWB3 pass filter over the bulb, to prove I could. That was the easy part [for me, its what I do a lot of]. Can anyone suggest efficient modifications of the electronics? It is powered by a 19.2vdc rechargeable Li Ion battery pack. The original fluorescent bulb is 13W, 110VAC; the UV-C bulb is 13W 60VAC. Attachement 1 is a basic schematic of the existing electronic design.[image] Attachment 2 is the UV-C replacement lamp.[image] :{

Comment: Why would you replace the lens with something opaque? An opaque lens would completely block any light/UV from passing through. Did you mean 'translucent' instead?

Comment: What circuit modifications do you expect necessary/useful? The discharge is independent from presence of phosphors or transmissivity at different wave lengths. Check power input - if less than 15 W, I'd trust the lamp to be driven below spec. (*field illumination* as in microscopy?)

Comment: To clarify, the lens for the original fluorescent light is transparent; I created a new part that is opaque except has an opening where the rectangular UV filter will be installed directly over the bulb.

Comment: The UV bulb does not start up just by replacing the fluorescent bulb with it; would the transformer need to be modified? Or would it be best to build a new circuit/board? - No, field as in 'out in the field' - mineral illumination.